# Flutter firebase receiving notification when closed or in background - How to show dialog with message

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

`I'm developing a Flutter app that utilizes Firebase push notifications, and I'm relatively new to mobile development.

I'm facing challenges with implementing a feature where, upon receiving a message, the app should display a popup modal with the message text. The popup modal successfully displays when the app is in the foreground.

However, I encounter two issues:

When I set up background messaging and use FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);, I encounter errors during app execution. The specific error is _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value).

Additionally, I would like the app to receive messages when it's in the background or the screen is locked. When the user unlocks the screen and navigates to the app, I want the popup modal to display the received data from the notification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may not have been able to update the updated notification classes. So I'll show you the API I use for notifications and let you know where you should call it. Here is the class I use for notification;

```
         import 'dart:developer';
         
         import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';
         import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
         import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
         import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
         import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
         import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
         
         import '../app_utils/common.dart';
         
         class PushNotificationsManager {
           PushNotificationsManager._();
         
           factory PushNotificationsManager() => _instance;
         
           static final PushNotificationsManager _instance =
           PushNotificationsManager._();
         
           //initialising firebase message plugin
           late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
           late final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
           FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
         
           AndroidNotificationChannel createNotificationChannel() {
             return const AndroidNotificationChannel(
               'High Importance Channel',
               'High Importance Notifications',
               importance: Importance.high,
             );
           }
         
           AndroidNotificationDetails createNotificationDetails(
               AndroidNotificationChannel channel) {
             return AndroidNotificationDetails(
               channel.id.toString(),
               channel.name.toString(),
               channelDescription: channel.description.toString(),
               importance: Importance.high,
               groupKey: channel.groupId,
               priority: Priority.high,
             );
           }
         
           // function to request notifications permissions
           void requestNotificationPermission() async {
             NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
                 alert: true,
                 announcement: true,
                 badge: true,
                 carPlay: true,
                 criticalAlert: true,
                 provisional: true,
                 sound: true);
         
             if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
               debugPrint('user granted permission');
             } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
                 AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
               debugPrint('user granted provisional permission');
             } else {
               AppSettings.openAppSettings(type: AppSettingsType.notification);
               debugPrint('user denied permission');
             }
           }
         
           //function to initialise flutter local notification plugin to show notifications for android when app is active
           void initLocalNotifications(
               BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
             var androidInitializationSettings =
             const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
             var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();
         
             var initializationSetting = InitializationSettings(
                 android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);
         
             await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
               initializationSetting,
               onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
                 handleMessage(message);
               },
             );
           }
         
           void firebaseInit(BuildContext context) {
             FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
               initLocalNotifications(context, message);
               showNotification(message);
             });
           }
         
           // function to show visible notification when app is active
           Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
             const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
             DarwinNotificationDetails(
                 presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);
         
             NotificationDetails notificationDetailsPlatformSpecific =
             NotificationDetails(
                 android: createNotificationDetails(createNotificationChannel()),
                 iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);
         
             showDefaultNotification(message.notification!.title ?? "",
                 message.notification!.body!, notificationDetailsPlatformSpecific);
           }
         
           void showDefaultNotification(String title, String body,
               NotificationDetails notificationDetailsPlatformSpecific) {
             Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
               await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                 0,
                 title.toString(),
                 body,
                 notificationDetailsPlatformSpecific,
               );
             });
           }
         
           //function to get device token on which we will send the notifications
           Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
             String? deviceId = await _messaging.getToken();
             Common.deviceToken.value = deviceId!;
             return deviceId;
           }
         
           void isTokenRefresh() async {
             _messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
               event.toString();
               log('refresh');
             });
           }
         
           //handle tap on notification when app is in background or terminated
           Future<void> setupInteractMessage(context) async {
             // when app is terminated
             RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
             await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
             if (initialMessage != null) {
               handleMessage(initialMessage);
             }
             //when app ins background
             FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
               handleMessage(event);
             });
             FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_handleBackgroundMessage);
           }
         
           Future<void> _handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
             handleMessage(message);
           }
         
           void handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
             if (message.notification!.body!.contains("")) {}
           }
         }
```

Now You can use it in MyApp class

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
  }

 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
 void initState() {
   PushNotificationsManager().requestNotificationPermission();
   PushNotificationsManager().firebaseInit(context);
   PushNotificationsManager().setupInteractMessage(context);
   //notificationServices.isTokenRefresh();
   PushNotificationsManager().getDeviceToken().then((value) {
  debugPrint('device token');
  debugPrint(value);
});   
super.initState();
}
```

Comment: create a class for notification like I did then use it in MyApp class initstate that's it you will get notification when is terminated and background